# How can I add a level to a MultiIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

```
index = [np.array(['foo', 'foo', 'qux']),
         np.array(['a', 'b', 'a'])]
data = np.random.randn(3, 2)
columns = ["X", "Y"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)
df.index.names = ["Level0", "Level1"]
print df

                      X         Y
Level0 Level1                    
foo    a       0.418549  0.252685
       b      -1.307099  0.202833
qux    a       0.046095 -0.968976
```

**New level**

I want to take the index of df and create a new MultiIndex that now has an additional level.

```
new_level_name = "New level"
new_level_labels = ['p', 'q']
# new_multi-index
```

**Desired MultiIndex**

```
Level0 Level1 Level2                    
foo    a      p       
              q       
       b      p      
              q       
qux    a      p      
              q
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simpliest is use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with new `DataFrame` with columns by new level values:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=1,index=df.index, columns=new_level_labels).stack()
df1.index.names = ['Level0','Level1',new_level_name]
print (df1)
Level0  Level1  New level
foo     a       p            1
                q            1
        b       p            1
                q            1
qux     a       p            1
                q            1
dtype: int64

print (df1.index)
MultiIndex(levels=[['foo', 'qux'], ['a', 'b'], ['p', 'q']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=['Level0', 'Level1', 'New level'])
```

Comment: ah brill! I had tried almost the exact same thing, but didn't include data=1!

Comment: Yes, I try it too, but if not `1` there are default `NaN`  and all rows are removed.

Comment: The result is actually a pd.Series, not DataFrame (?). Can't believe there is no better method...

Comment: @n1000 - Do you think `print (df.reindex(df1.index))` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what data should be in your desired DataFrame, but for a similar problem I used `melt()`:

```
df1 = df.reset_index()
pd.melt(df1, id_vars=['Level0', 'Level1'])


    Level0  Level1  variable    value
0   foo a   X   0.678564
1   foo b   X   -0.609134
2   qux a   X   0.505178
3   foo a   Y   -2.593380
4   foo b   Y   -0.232796
5   qux a   Y   -1.420875
```