# How to efficiently add level to pandas series index to create a multilevel?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, multi-index, prepend

I want to prepend a level to a `pd.Index` on a `pd.Series` to make it `pd.MultiIndex`.  The most obvious way that I have done in the past is to iterate through everything with `map` and create a `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples`.  However, my newest dataset has REALLY big idicies the largest of which is 282763074 so it takes very long.

I found the following this stackoverflow post: [How can I add a level to a MultiIndex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42612236/how-can-i-add-a-level-to-a-multiindex) and this sped up my calculation but I can't stop to think that there must be a faster way to do this instead of creating a `pd.DataFrame` first.

**Does anyone know of a quicker way to do this?  Is there some method on `pd.Index` or `pd.MultIndex` that allows for this type of quick computation?**

```
n = int(1e6)
x = pd.Series(range(n))
def f1(x):
    x.index = x.index.map(lambda i: ("LEVEL_0",i))
    return x

def f2(x):
    old_idx = x.index.to_frame()
    old_idx.insert(0, "LEVEL_0", "LEVEL_0")
    x.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(old_idx, names=[None,None])
    return x

%time a = f1(x)
x = pd.Series(range(n))
%time b = f2(x)
np.all(a == b)

# CPU times: user 2.6 s, sys: 128 ms, total: 2.73 s
# Wall time: 2.72 s
# CPU times: user 555 ms, sys: 73 ms, total: 628 ms
# Wall time: 627 ms
```

Comment: on my side, `pd.concat([x], keys=['LEVEL_0'])` is about 10x faster but is limited to one value you can really prepend in the level

Comment: @Ben.T adding one value is exactly what I need to do.  I didn't realize this would work for a `pd.Series` as well!!