# Creating a MultiIndex pandas dataframe with columns from Excel files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I managed to add lower-levels to MultiIndex as shown here using `.stack()`:

[How can I add a level to a MultiIndex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42612236/how-can-i-add-a-level-to-a-multiindex)

With

```
lists

[('C5P', 'CI3'),
 ('C2P', 'CI4'),
 ('C1', 'CI3'),
 ('C7', 'CI4'),
 ('C3P', 'CI1'),
 ('C3P', 'CI2'),
 ('C4', 'CI1'),
 ('C3P', 'CI3'),
 ('C4P', 'CI4'),
 ('C5P', 'CI2'),
 ('C4P', 'CI3'),
 ('C3P', 'CI4'),
 ('C2P', 'CI2'),
 ('C6', 'CI2'),
 ('C7', 'CI2'),
 ('C7', 'CI3'),
 ('C1P', 'CI1'),
 ('C2P', 'CI3'),
 ('C2', 'CI1'),
 ('C4P', 'CI2'),
 ('C2', 'CI2'),
 ('C3', 'CI2'),
 ('C1P', 'CI2'),
 ('C6', 'CI1'),
 ('C3', 'CI3'),
 ('C1', 'CI1'),
 ('C5P', 'CI1'),
 ('C3P', 'CI4'),
 ('C5', 'CI2'),
 ('C4', 'CI2')]

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(lists,names=['borehole','sample'])

d = pd.DataFrame(data=1,index=index, columns=['1','2','3']).stack()
e = pd.DataFrame(data=1,index=d.index, columns=['p','q']).stack()
```

The result is something like:

```
borehole  sample      
C4        CI1     1  p    1
                     q    1
                  2  p    1
                     q    1
                  3  p    1
                     q    1
          CI2     1  p    1
                     q    1
                  2  p    1
                     q    1
                  3  p    1
                     q    1
C5P       CI3     1  p    1
                     q    1
                  2  p    1
                     q    1
                  3  p    1
                     q    1
          CI2     1  p    1
                     q    1
                  2  p    1
                     q    1
                  3  p    1
                     q    1
          CI1     1  p    1
                     q    1
                  2  p    1
                     q    1
                  3  p    1
                     q    1
```

What I would actually like to obtain is to have this arranged in columns and populate columns 'p' and 'q' from Excel files. I am stuck at trying to assign data to p and q.
Sample data as follows:

```
borehole    C5P                     
sample      CI2                     
specimen    1                       2                       3       
            p           q           p           q           p           q   
            140.5745654 90.9496963  157.5959379 101.2858137 236.882037  105.4921111 
            140.8908259 91.01647765 157.4825549 101.4976646 236.6523714 105.2591143 
            141.1076296 91.08488883 157.3080705 101.8022116         
            141.3524628 91.17138846 157.3539987 102.167996          
            143.2526588 92.28797636                 
            143.776291  92.62887289
```

Comment: Your example is not reproducible, missing `index`.

Comment: What do your excel file and your `index` variable look like?

Comment: @Driftr95, excel files with q p columns of equal length but varying from file to file

Comment: @user2078621 but what are the contents of the columns in the files like? how do you want to line them up with your `index`? do you just want to use the values in the columns repeated like you are with `[1,2,3]` and `['p','q']`?

Comment: @Driftr95 edited with sample data

Comment: @user2078621 Are specimens 1, 2, and 3 from the same file? Would you mind using `df.to_dict('tight')` so I can reproduce it exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not quite sure I understand your exactly what you're dealing with and what you want in the end, but if your sample DataFrame is recreated<sup>**([view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOaAC.png))**</sup> with

> ```py
> df = pd.DataFrame([
>   [140.5745654, 90.9496963, 157.5959379, 101.2858137, 236.882037, 105.4921111],
>   [140.8908259, 91.01647765, 157.4825549, 101.4976646,236.6523714,105.2591143],
>   [141.1076296, 91.08488883, 157.3080705, 101.8022116],
>   [141.3524628, 91.17138846, 157.3539987, 102.167996],
>   [143.2526588, 92.28797636], [143.776291, 92.62887289]
> ], columns=pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
>     ('C5P', 'CI2', 1, 'p'), ('C5P', 'CI2', 1, 'q'), ('C5P', 'CI2', 2, 'p'), 
>     ('C5P', 'CI2', 2, 'q'), ('C5P', 'CI2', 3, 'p'), ('C5P', 'CI2', 3, 'q')
> ], names=['borehole', 'sample','specimen', '']))
> ```

then if you `.pivot` and `.stack` again:

```py
df_pivot = df.T.reset_index().pivot(['borehole', 'sample','specimen'], '', )
df_stack = df_pivot.swaplevel(0,1,1).stack(1)
```

| `df_pivot.T` | `df_stack` | `df_stack.droplevel(3, axis='index')` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: pivot_t]<sub>([`df_pivot`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/055W5.png) has been transposed to fit better)</sub> | [image: stack]_____________________________ | [image: droplevl]____ |

---

#### ADDED EDIT: Single-Column DF

```py
df.T.stack().to_frame().swaplevel().sort_index() ## OR
# df.unstack().to_frame().swaplevel().sort_index()
```

[image: desired]

Comment: that's great, thank you  so much for your help. What I would actually achieve is exactly like the left example you provided, but with p and q being sub level columns of each 1, 2, 3 specimen like what I showed in my post.

Comment: @user2078621 that's actually even easier: just use `df.T.stack().to_frame().swaplevel().sort_index()` ([view result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tU698.png)) or *`df.unstack().to_frame().swaplevel().sort_index()`*

Comment: the piece of code that you proposed in your answer, prior to any ```.pivot``` and ```.stack``` does exactly what I want. Now the only problem is that I have data in columns, not in rows as in your code! How can I use data in columns provided they have different lengths?

Comment: Just transpose with `.T`? But that's all I'm doing before *prior to any `.pivot` and `.stack`*, so you'd just be reversing that...? I'm even more confused now...

Comment: Does [my `df`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOaAC.png) look like it's meant to be btw? and would you mind manually mocking up an output for your sample data that looks like you'd want it to in the end? [Also, can I see that `df.to_dict('tight')` snippet I mentioned before? And whether the sample data is all from one file of 3(?) separate files?]

Comment: Sorry if that feels like too many questions, but I do need that info to properly reproduce your data and to understand what you want....

Comment: Yes, your df looks exactly as it is meant to be. Clearly there'll be more "boreholes", other "samples" for each borehole, and "specimens" 1, 2, 3 for each sample. The Excel files are named [borehole]_[sample].xlsx and contain various columns, among which the "p" and "q" I want to extract. The length of the columns may differ from file to file.